# Check if telephone number contains whitespace in i-th position

Tags: sql, database, db2, constraints

i want write a constraint that checks if the 4-th position of a telephone number is a whitespace. So for example

+34 12334... should be allowed

+341234... should NOT be allowed.

My telephone number is of type VARCHAR(50).

Comment: I'd recommend a trigger instead, that fixes the format if not ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this :

```
ALTER TABLE yourlib.yourtablename ADD CONSTRAINT 
yourlib.yourconstraintname CHECK (telephone is null or length(telephone)>4 and substring(telephone, 4, 1)=' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something with charindex, which searches for a particular string within a string and returns its position

```
select telephone 
FROM table
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', Telephone) = 4
```

for the first number listed the result would be 4 and the second would return 0 (not found)